# Selenium Chrome Full Screen With Capabilities

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, maximize

In my test code, I define some capabilities and get ChromeDriver like this:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

But I need to open Chrome in full screen in Mac OS X. I searched and saw that this code is used to maximize:

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("--kiosk");
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

But I have to use capabilities with Chrome driver and there is no ChromeDriver constructor that takes options ve capabilities. How can I use ChromeDriver capabilitest and options to open Chrome maximize in Mac OS X?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `chromeOptions` to `capabilities`

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("--kiosk");
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: I don't know the reason but this isn't working on os x.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't work, too. But I have to define driver like this:

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);